# Interactive Markers Teleop (groovy) has rviz error and doesn't work

Tags: ros, markers

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all, I have a turtlebot 2. I roslaunch "turtlebot_bringup minimal.launch" on turtlebot and configure the network as http://wiki.ros.org/turtlebot/Tutorials/groovy/Network%20Configuration. Afterwards I run commands (http://wiki.ros.org/turtlebot_interactive_markers/Tutorials/UsingTurtlebotInteractiveMarkers) on my workstation I met errors: Grid and RobotModel on the left of rviz window are red-marked, and both of then have a sub-red-marked Status: Error. After choosing InteractiveMarkes and Interact, I dragged the mouse but turtlebot didn't move. Pls give me a hand, thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/145571/interactive-markers-teleop-(groovy)-has-rviz-error-and-doesn%27t-work/) by [fuchangjie](https://answers.ros.org/users/9291/fuchangjie/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2014-03-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Did you try roslaunch turtlebot_teleop keyboard_teleop.launch? I recommend that you check whether turtlebot moves. I don't try InteractiveMarkers yet, but my experiment might be usefull for you http://answers.ros.org/question/139701/turtlebot2-doesnt-work-with-amcl_demolaunch/. I guess that the problem is /etc/hosts. I think that you need to check if your turtlebot receives messages that rviz publishes.

---

Originally posted by [Ken_in_JAPAN](https://answers.ros.org/users/11311/ken_in_japan/) with karma: 894 on 2014-03-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0